# Why is there no Application Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I know it sounds strange but I see that there's a application controller, helper and view but why no model for global/general use? I need a place to put scopes and methods that go across multiple models which wouldn't make sense if it was in one or the other. Can I do this now? Anybody have a way to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829174/hacking-activerecord-add-global-named-scope)?

Comment: @Michael So I should make a model called Scopes.rb? Good find.

Comment: @LearningRoR That's not a model, it's a module--it's basically the same as my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create a base model class, or a module. (Or both, I suppose.)

The module can be mixed in to ActiveRecord::Base or individual models.

You could also create class methods that include only specific scopes/methods, like:

```
included_scopes :foo, :bar
```

This can be helpful for documentation and readability so that functionality is explicit and obvious.

Which (or which combination) makes sense depends on specifics, but there's a few ideas to kick around.

Comment: Base model class? Could you give an example? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @LearningRoR `Foo < ActiveRecord::Base`, `MyModel < Foo`.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Looks like I will create a module and get to understanding these.

Comment: But wouldn't `MyModel < Foo` make a big mess when AR assumes that you're doing STI? AFAIK this is why there is no `ApplicationModel` available.

Comment: @muistooshort I'm not sure, you're probably right--I thought I'd done it in the past, but can't confirm/deny. What you're saying would make sense, though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the STI stuff would kick in, I think I've tried it and ended up doing a lot of swearing because STI is such a bad design choice in both the OO and relational realms.

Comment: @muistooshort It's a tradeoff implementation, for sure, especially because of questions like this one. I'll have to think about this some time.

Comment: when you do this, but don't want STI I think you should set `self.abstract_class = true` on the parent, this suppresses the STI.

Comment: @niels Ah, yes; that does sound familiar--maybe I did something along those lines.