# Group by hour and use user time zone in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have to show how many api calls made a user during each day for the last 30 days, in order to build a nice graph. I didn't have any problem so far with that. Something important to notice is that the database and system timezone is in UTC, but most of the users are located in Pacific Time (GMT -8).

In order to get the api usage grouped by the day of use, I can do something like

```
ApiCall.
  where(user_id: @user.id).
  where("requested_at > ?", Time.zone.now.to_date - 30.days).
  group("date(requested_at)").
  select("count(*) as qty, date(requested_at) as requested_at").all
```

Now the problem, is that the time for a user located in California, is far different from the time for a user located in England and that's where I'm failing.

A user makes an API Call, located in California, on 2012-12-14 21:00:00 GMT -8. The API CALL in the DB is stored with the time 2012-12-14 05:00:00  (because its in GMT, so it add 8 hours).

Now for that user, if I go to see my daily usage, with the query I did, it will show that my api call was not made on 2012-12-14 at 21:00:00, because on the database its stored as 2012-12-14 05:00:00, and for the user the api usage will show that he did that api call on the next day, and he will think that the system is not working fine.

So in few words, how can I group the api calls based on the user timezone and not based on the database timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, by using mysql convert timezone function, its not a nice solution yet it works

```
ApiCall.
  where(user_id: @user.id).
  where("requested_at > ?", Time.zone.now.to_date - 30.days).
  group("date(convert_tz(requested_at, '+00:00', '-08:00'))").
  select("count(*) as qty, date(requested_at) as requested_at").all
```

I'll add a bounty later to see if someone can tell me about a better solution to these kind of reports with rails and timezones

Answer (score 2):

You can set the time zone for the request and do the date sorting in Rails.

```
ApiCall.
  where(user_id: @user.id).
  where("requested_at > ?", Time.zone.now.to_date - 30.days).
  group_by({|api_call| api_call.requested_at.to_date})
```

Typically in Rails you set the time zone in a before_filter on a controller action.

```
Time.zone = current_user.time_zone if logged_in?
```

Comment: Yes, I know about Time.zone and I know about using ruby to group the records, although is much more effective to left the db engine to do the grouping, so what I'm really looking for is a good rails way to work with timezones and at the same time let the engine to do the complex operations.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Rails comes with this kind of scope that would convert DB dates in the user timezone before doing a 'group' over it.

But, you can define your own scope to handle that, for example :

```
class ApiCall  
  scope :group_by_date_in_timezone, lambda{|date_column| 
    group("date(convert_tz(#{date_column}, '+00:00', '#{Time.zone.formatted_offset}'))")
  }
```

Then your query becomes a bit clearer :

```
ApiCall.
  where(user_id: @user.id).
  where("requested_at > ?", Time.zone.now.to_date - 30.days).
  group_by_date_in_timezone(:requested_at).
  select("count(*) as qty, requested_at").all

  # 'date(requested_at) as requested_at' would be also in DB Time zone
  # Instead we can select 'requested_at' to let Rails do the user timezone conversion
  # you can easily convert it to a date later with #to_date
```

This scope may also be useful for other models, then you could define it as a global ActiveRecord scope, following the answer of this question: [Hacking ActiveRecord: add global named scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829174/hacking-activerecord-add-global-named-scope).

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but here comes the Postgresql answer:

First define this var to make things more readable:

```
requested_at_day = "date(requested_at AT TIME ZONE \'UTC\'
              AT TIME ZONE \'#{Time.zone.tzinfo.identifier}\')"
```

Then:

```
ApiCall.
  where(user_id: @user.id).
  where("requested_at > ?", Time.zone.now.to_date - 30.days).
  group(requested_at_day).
  select("count(*) as qty, #{requested_at_day} as requested_at_day").all
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a good practice to store all the records in UTC, so nothing needs to be converted and the time internval will be computed correctly. Only convert to the user's local time zone when presenting the time to the user.

Comment: I'm already storing everything in UTC, and the problem came when I have to group either by day or hour, because the users has different timezones.

Comment: well, in that case it's easy, since everything is in UTC, when the user query the api call he make on a certain day (his local time), just convert his local time to the UTC time equivalent in the db and use that to construct the query.
In your example, the user's api call since his local time 12/14 21:00 will becomes the db's UTC time since 12/15 5:00

Comment: But that takes me back to the original question. Lets say that you are located in LA, so its GMT-8. The db stores the date and time in GMT+0. You made 50 api calls yesterday at 10 PM and another 50 at 4 AM today. The db stores both on today, the first ones at 6 AM and the others at 12 PM. If I group by day, the db will group with timezone GMT+0, so it will say that you made 100 api calls today, but I need it to say that you made 50 api calls today and do the right timezone conversions, and I was looking a cleaner way to do it taking advantage of rails timezones.

Comment: It's a matter of how you define "today"
In your case, you need it to say the user made 50 api calls "today" it implies that you define "today" in the user's point of view, so that means you have to do the translation to the correct server time frame when you handle the request. 
let's say the user logged in at 5AM GMT-8, and he's interested at looking at his api calls "today", that will translate to a request of looking up his api calls since GMT+0 8AM ~ now (which is GMT+0 1PM).
And every user will have a different "today", I think that's ok since the analytic data is presented to a user.